# "String.h" VS <string.h>

Tags: c++

Friends

On HP-UX box when Iam passing a string object to function 
Im getting the following below error

**Error 422: "../header/Handler.h", line 24 # 'string' is used as a type, but has not been 
defined as a type. Perhaps you meant 'String' as in class String**

```
["/opt/aCC/include/SC/String.h", line 66].

        int populateBindingHandle(rpc_if_handle_t p_if_spec, string p_cell_name);
```

why would I get an error to use String.h not

how does a declaration String newstr;

different from

string newstr; ??

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is a `String` class in the header mentioned by the compiler. The compiler thinks you made a typo.

If you want to use STL strings use the following:

```
#include <string>

int populateBindingHandle(rpc_if_handle_t p_if_spec, std::string ...)
```

or have a `using` declaration somewhere:

```
using std::string;

int populateBindingHandle(rpc_if_handle_t p_if_spec, std::string ...)
```

Note, the old-style headers have been deprecated, i.e. you should no longer use `#include <string.h>`

Comment: Looks like some old `aCC` specific library class. I don't think you'd need that.